# Group many columns by index instead of by label in a pandas Groupby statement

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with +60 columns. I need to group by two columns, and only need one column values summed. The problem is if I don't manually type the names of all the column labels in the groupby statement, columns not included will not appear in the output.

Instead of something like this:

```
df_final.groupby(by=['OrderNo','ItemSKU','CustName',.......'20th Column'],as_index=False).sum()
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
df_final.groupby(by=[:20],as_index=False).sum()
```

How can I do this and avoid typing all those column names?

Here is a print of the column datatypes:

```
>>> print(df_final.dtypes)
OrderNo                   float64
PledgeID                    int64
ReferrerID                float64
FulfillmentStatus          object
FundingDate                object
PaymentMethod             float64
Appearance                 object
Name                       object
Email                      object
Amount                     object
PlatformFee                object
PerkID                    float64
Perk                       object
ShippingName               object
ShippingPhoneNumber        object
ShippingAddress            object
ShippingAddress2           object
ShippingCity               object
ShippingState/Province     object
ShippingZip/PostalCode     object
ShippingCountry            object
ItemSKU                    object
ArticleName                object
UPC                       float64
ArticleQty                  int64
dtype: object
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert first 20 columns names to list:

```
df_final.groupby(by=df_final.columns[:20].tolist(),as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: This is very close. I'm getting an empty dataframe for some reason though.  
`>>> df_final.groupby(by=df_final.columns[:19].tolist(),as_index=False).sum()  

Empty DataFrame  

Columns: [OrderNo, PledgeID, ReferrerID, FulfillmentStatus, FundingDate, PaymentMethod, Appearance, Name, Email, Amount, PlatformFee, PerkID, Perk, ShippingName, ShippingPhoneNumber, ShippingAddress, ShippingAddress2, ShippingCity, ShippingState/Province, UPC, ArticleQty]  

Index: []  
>>> df_final.shape  
(24711, 25)`

Comment: @rabbitholefinder - What is `print (df.dtypes)` ? It seems there are next columns not numeric.

Comment: Thanks. I added the output to the question. The result exceeded the allowable # of characters for a comment. :-)

Comment: @rabbitholefinder - hmmm, last 2 columns are float and int, so it should be aggregated.

Comment: @rabbitholefinder - Ii thinkI find problem, in `print (df_final.dtypes)` is different like `print (df.dtypes)`. Sorry, I think `print (df_final.dtypes)`

Comment: @rabbitholefinder - Also I suggest check number of columns in `df_final`, maybe grouping by all columns.

Comment: thanks. I checked them again, but not sure what to do.
  
I just need to sum the ArticleQty for the OrderNo / ItemSKU pairs. Everything else needs to remain the same. Unfortunately, the UPC codes and other numeric values are getting summed up as well.  

I really need all of that to stay the same. The SKU, ArticleName, UPC should all be unchanged. Only combine duplicates and sum up the Qty value. 

I used to do this in mysql and it was not so complicated. :)

Comment: Hmmm, what return `print(df_final.columns[:19].tolist())` ?

Comment: Here is the output:
`>>> exec(open('FirstNormalize.py').read(), globals())
just printed outputdata to the csv file
>>> print(df_final.columns[:19].tolist())
['OrderNo', 'PledgeID', 'ReferrerID', 'FulfillmentStatus', 'FundingDate', 'PaymentMethod', 'Appearance', 'Name', 'Email', 'Amount', 'PlatformFee', 'PerkID', 'Perk', 'ShippingName', 'ShippingPhoneNumber', 'ShippingAddress', 'ShippingAddress2', 'ShippingCity', 'ShippingState/Province']`

Comment: Here are the datatypes:

Comment: @rabbitholefinder - I thinking about it a lot and I find problem. there are some `NaN`s values in first 19 columns and `NA` groups in `GroupBy` are automatically excluded [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby)

Comment: I will try again. I had to populate all NaN values in the csv file. maybe it will work now??

Comment: Jezrael, fantastic!! Together we solved it! Those NaN values were causing problems in other operations so I bulk replaced them with a dummy value. After that, everything worked. I just never tried the groupby again. Thanks. I'd almost given up. :)